fetch data before render component in reactjs
i try fetch data from server before render but it render without fetch data in spite of i use hook
const { id_product } = useParams();
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/product/details/${id_product}`, {
            method: "GET",
        });
        const data = await res.json();
        if (data.success === false) {
            console.log(data.message);
            return;
        }
        setProduct(data);
        setLoading(false);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("fetch");
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            fetchData();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }, [id_product]);
    return (
        product && !loading && (
            ///// render data 
        )
    );

i try log something in useEffect but it dont log

Hi, The function is fetchData() is async, therefore please evaluate with await as this : await fetchData() instead of fetchData().

React setState is an asynchronous operation, so there might be a issue with you updating the state in the useEffect.
You can change the initial state of loading to be true, so then only when you have the data setLoading to false.
So change
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
to
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
And remove the setLoading(true) from the useEffect
